# Assign "Command" key on external keyboard in Chrome OS

Tags: keyboard-layout, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm using an external Mac keyboard with a Chromebook (Chrome OS). Apparently the Command key is unassigned because it doesn't work as a modifier. It would be really helpful if it even just duplicated the the Control key's function, but I see no way to assign it in the keyboard settings. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The Command key functions as "Search" when pressed on its own. The Chromebook's internal keyboard uses caps lock is search, whereas the external keyboard uses caps lock for its intended function (caps lock), so the unused Command key becomes "Search".

So remap "Search" to "Control" in:

*Settings* → *Device* → *Keyboard Settings*, and set "Search" to map to "Ctrl".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Command is now under External Meta, so you can change that to *Ctrl*.

But by default, it is still set to search:

[image: Image of settings]